# Angular service test - Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function thrown

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

When I send a request in my `example.service.ts` everything works fine and I can iterate the response as shown below.

example.service.ts:

```
this.returnExampleData().subscribe((response: any) => {

  response.forEach(element => {

    console.log(element)

  })
});
```

However when I run the same method in my service test I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function thrown`. Any ideas on how I can access JSON body from the response? At the moment `console.log (response)` prints something like this `LOG: HttpResponse{headers: HttpHeaders{normalizedNames: Map{}, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function () { ... }}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'http://example.url', ok: true, type: 4, body: [Object{id: ..., field1: ..., field2: ..., ...`

example.service.spec.ts:

```
describe('ExampleService', () => {
  let service: ExampleService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ExampleService);
  });

  it('Example', (done: DoneFn) => {


    service.returnExampleData().subscribe((response: any) => {

      console.log(response) // Above is the result of the log

      response.forEach(element => {

        console.log(element)

      })
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You should not make actual API call to test a service. Refer https://shashankvivek-7.medium.com/testing-services-in-angular-karma-ed49f8d5b264

Comment: @ShashankVivek I just want to execute very basic integration test with another component.